# Hadoop - split manually files in HDFS

Tags: file, hadoop, split, hdfs

I have submitted a file with size 1 GB and I want to split this file in files with size 100MB. How can I do that from the command line.
I'm searching for a command like:

```
hadoop fs -split --bytes=100m /user/foo/one_gb_file.csv /user/foo/100_mb_file_1-11.csv
```

Is there a way to do that in HDFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HDFS, we cannot expect all feature that are available in unix. Current version of hadoop fs utility doesn't provide this functionality. May be we can expect in future. you can raise a bug(improvement in apache Jira) for including this feature in hdfs.

For now you got to write your own implementation in Java.